# Python Django Caching a processed EMail object

Tags: python, django, email, caching

I am trying to fetch emails from a mail server.On click of pagination buttons I fetch 20 mails.But as we go previous and next it takes too much time to get and parse the email message and create the email object which has information about a particular email.
Below is the code which I am now using

```
 #Fetching list of all active emailmessage UIDs
 result, data = m.uid('search', None, searchKey) # search all email and return uids
        offset = int(request.POST.get('offset','0'))
        msg_summry=[]
        if result == 'OK':
            uidlist=data[0].split()
            uidlist.reverse()
            for num in uidlist[offset:offset+20]:

                # to read message without affecting seen flag
                result, data = m.uid('fetch', num, "(FLAGS BODY.PEEK[HEADER] BODYSTRUCTURE)")
                readStatus= hasAttach="No"
                if result == 'OK':

                    # for getting readStatus
                    if "\Seen" not in data[0][0] :
                        readStatus="Yes"

                    #checking for attachment 
                    email_message = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])    
                    if '("attachment" ' in data[1][:]:
                        hasAttach="Yes"

                    #parsing email date to specific format
                    date=email_message['Date']
                    tmp = parsedate_tz(date)
                    if not tmp:
                        mail_date= date
                    else:
                        try:
                            ndate = datetime(*(tmp)[:7])
                            now = datetime.now()
                            if now - ndate > timedelta(7):
                                mail_date= ndate.strftime("%b %d, %Y")
                            else:    
                                mail_date= ndate.strftime("%a %I:%M %p")
                        except ValueError:
                            mail_date= date 

                    #Email parsed Object
                    mail_data = {'fields'   :{'mid' : num,
                                              'from' : email_message['From'],
                                              'read': readStatus,
                                              'sub' : decode_header(email_message['Subject'])[0][0],
                                              'attach' : hasAttach,
                                              'mdate' : mail_date,
                                              },
                        }

                    #list of parsed objects
                    msg_summry.append(mail_data)
```

How can I speed up this operation? 
I heard caching is one good solution but how to do it.Since mails cane be deleted in between or marked as read or unread or their UID can be expired

Comment: Probably need to move in direction of fetching emails in background and storing them locally, then use local copy for display and pagination. And to make sure it's up to date need to be refetching them periodically, unless that mail server can help with notifying about the changes somehow. My desktop email client just downloads new mails once every 5 minutes and it's not worried about whether I read them or deleted them through web form after that, it's just a copy.

Comment: My code should work for multiple mail domains as well as multiple users as well .So will background fetch be a good idea. Because mail support is only a small feature in the entire platform. Also is the 5 minutes job run good enough ,since a new message will only be reflected after 5 minutes